# Trying to check if the number the user entered through the input function is within a range of numbers

Tags: python, input, while-loop, range

I am currently still learning Python using a course on Udemy.
I've reached a project where I have to code out a BlackJack game.

```
if self.total not in range(0,1000): 
self.total = int(input("How many chips would you like to bring to the table? (0 - 1000): "))
```

something like this.

I want the input to continue running if the number they provided is not within 0 to 1000. But I am getting an error with the syntax, specifically the (in) keyword.

I tried using a while loop, but the same syntax error kept appearing. I checked and (in) can be used to check if a number is within a range().
So what am I missing here?

I also forgot to mention that this project requires us to use Object-oriented Programming, and creating our own classes.

Comment: can you provide whole error message?

Comment: Try `if 0 <= self.total <= 999` instead (or `<= 1000` if you meant to include it)

Comment: Don't pass the return value from *input()* to *int()* without using an exception handler

Comment: The error points to the (in) keyword and says incorrect/wrong syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It is very common to see code of this style:

```
x = int(input('Enter a number: '))
```

This is very bad practice because any value entered that cannot be represented as an integer will cause a ValueError to be raised and unless handled properly the program will terminate.

Here's a more robust approach. Yes, there's a lot more code but it will keep you out of trouble.

```
def get_chips(lo, hi):
    while True:
        inval = input(f'How many chips would you like to bring to the table? ({lo} - {hi}): ')
        try:
            chips = int(inval)
            if lo <= chips <= hi:
                return chips
            raise ValueError('Not in range')
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f'{e} - Please try again')

print(get_chips(0, 1000))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, I haven't learned the keyword (raise). what does it do in this instance?

Comment: I recommend this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

1. The statement `x in y` requires that `y` is a list

   Hence you should use `if self.total not in [i for i in range(0,1000)]`
2. The above would yield pretty poor performance during runtime, because in the worst case, the value of `self.total` would be compared to each element in the list

   Hence, since `self.total` is integer, you should use `if 0 <= self.total <= 1000`
3. Note that `1000` is in fact not in `range(0,1000)`, because this range runs from 0 to 999

   If that is what you actually intended for, then you should use `if 0 <= self.total < 1000`

Comment: #1 not entirely correct. Y can be any object that implements __contains__ such as set, tuple, dict, list or indeed any custom class that fulfils that requirement

Comment: @OlvinRoght: True, but this is a newb, so I figured I'd better keep it simple for him/her.

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot and I am a newb. Just started python 3 months ago.